# Move Form1 when I move Form2 in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms. `Form2` is being opened from `Form1`, like this:

```
Form2.ShowDialog();
```

`StartPosition` of `Form2` is configured to `centerParent`.

I need to fix position `Form2` in Form1's center, so that when I move `Form2`, `Form1` also changes its location. I have tried many solutions without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to include the parent reference when calling the ShowDialog function, but you would also have to record the initial position difference *before* using the LocationChanged event.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
f2.ShowDialog(this);
```

Then in the dialog form, you can wire it up like this:

```
Point parentOffset = Point.Empty;
bool wasShown = false;

public Form2() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
  parentOffset = new Point(this.Left - this.Owner.Left,
                           this.Top - this.Owner.Top);
  wasShown = true;
  base.OnShown(e);
}

protected override void OnLocationChanged(EventArgs e) {
  if (wasShown) {
    this.Owner.Location = new Point(this.Left - parentOffset.X, 
                                    this.Top - parentOffset.Y);
  }
  base.OnLocationChanged(e);
}
```

This code isn't doing any error checking, demonstration code only.

Comment: thanks for this solution! I was looking this code! thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Please do beware that this is in general a **very** undesirable UI feature.  Dialogs are annoying because they disable the rest of the windows in the app.  Which prevents the user from activating a window to have a look at its content.  All that the user can do is move a dialog out of the way.  You are intentionally preventing this from working.

Anyhoo, easy enough to implement with the LocationChanged event.  Paste this code in the dialog form class:

```
    private Point oldLocation = new Point(int.MaxValue, 0);

    protected override void OnLocationChanged(EventArgs e) {
        if (oldLocation.X != int.MaxValue && this.Owner != null) {
            this.Owner.Location = new Point(
                this.Owner.Left + this.Left - oldLocation.X,
                this.Owner.Top + this.Top - oldLocation.Y);
        }
        oldLocation = this.Location;
        base.OnLocationChanged(e);
    }
```

Comment: Hello Hans, sorry for my incompetence, but I need add this code in form2? And after, how implement LocationChanged event (in form2)? thanks for your patience.

Comment: As noted, copy-paste this into the dialog form, Form2.  No need to implement the event, that's already taken care of by OnLocationChanged.  Try it.

Comment: done, without success. If I try to move form2, form1 doesn't move :(