# move for header form 1 and form 2

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

Good day!

There are 2 forms. When you click on the button of the first form, form2 appears at the second border

```vb
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CenterToScreen()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim frm1Width As Integer = Width
        Dim frm1Top As Integer = Top
        Dim frm1Left As Integer = Left
        Dim delta As Integer = 485


        Form2.Show()
        Form2.Top = frm1Top
        Form2.Left = frm1Left - frm1Width + delta

    End Sub
```

In form2 there is a ban on moving beyond the heading

```vb
 Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef message As Message)
        Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
        Const SC_MOVE As Integer = &HF010

        Select Case message.Msg
            Case WM_SYSCOMMAND
                Dim command As Integer = message.WParam.ToInt32() And &HFFF0
                If command = SC_MOVE Then
                    Return
                End If
        End Select

        MyBase.WndProc(message)
    End Sub
```

Tell me how to make it so that it would be possible to move both forms beyond the header of form 1?

Comment: In case you mean [Move Form1 when I move Form2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796367/move-form1-when-i-move-form2-in-c-sharp). You can convert it to vb.net online.

Comment: It's not quite clear what your requirement is. I *guess* you need to use a single form, hide the first content page, and show the seconds content page. All in the same form; and the content could be in some UserControls or [wizard-like pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40633229/3110834).