# move Form2 according to form1

Tags: c#, winforms

My problem is:

i want Form 2 to be moved only when I move form 1, and it will always stay beneath Form1.

i tried everything i could think of:  Location point and set desktop position, i tried a timer of realtime moving , i just cant get it , this shouldn't be so difficult :(

[image]

i'm using a panel to move form 1

```
 private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mov = 1;
            movX = e.X;
            movY = e.Y;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mov == 1)
            {
                this.SetDesktopLocation(MousePosition.X - movX, MousePosition.Y - movY);
            }
        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mov = 0;

        }
```

i also tried to make One form and put panels in it and make the form transparent, but i get an issue when i'm trying to move the form via the panel.

Answer (score 0):

i found solution on this:

[Move Form1 when I move Form2 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796367/move-form1-when-i-move-form2-in-c-sharp)

in first form:

```
 protected override void OnLocationChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (secondForm == null)
            {
                secondForm = new SecondForm();

            }
            if (secondForm.wasShown == true)
            {
                secondForm.Location = new Point(this.Left - parentOffset.X,
                                                this.Top - parentOffset.Y);
            }
            base.OnLocationChanged(e);
        }
```

in the second form:

```
public  bool wasShown = false;

 private void SecondForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            Location = new Point(topForm.lX -40, topForm.lY +85);
            wasShown = true;
            this.Owner = topForm;

        }
```